# Regex: How to Print Name of a matched Group

Tags: java, regex

I have a java code to check whether the input string is matching with Regular Expression like this.

```
     String regexpr="(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})";
     String test="04/07/2016";
     p = Pattern.compile (regexpr);
     Matcher m = p.matcher (test);
         while(m.find ())
                 {
                      System.out.println("Matched String"+ m.group());
                      System.out.println("Group1:"+ m.start(1) + "-" + m.end(1) + "\t " + group(1));
                      System.out.println("Group2:"+ m.start(2) + "-" + m.end(2) + "\t " + group(2));
                      System.out.println("Group3:"+ m.start(3) + "-" + m.end(3) + "\t " + group(3));
                 }
```

It gives the the output as

```
     Matched String   04/07/2016
     Group:1    0-2   04
     Group:2   3-5    07
     Group:3   6-10   2016
```

In addition to this i also want to print the matched group names i.e

```
     Group1:  day    0-2      04
     Group2:  month  3-5      07
     Group3:  year   6-10     2016
```

Is there any method to do this in regex in java?

Comment: `System.out.println("Group1: day "+ m.start(1) + "to" + m.end(1) + "\t " + group(1));` You know which group you are printing why do you need dynamically get the name? And AFAIK there isn't any method to get a group name.

Comment: @Jorge Campos i'm just giving  an example, if in case we need to take all the input dynamically then what is the solution?

Comment: A regex pattern is static, as so you name your groups accordingly you will know either way where they are and when to use it. If you define your regex in a dynamic way your code to find the groups would also be equivalent to your dynamic code. Add a real example where you would need such feature. When a major language such as Java doesn't implements such feature you sure must ask why you need it.

Comment: It depends on how your dynamic input looks. Are you building the regexp from dynamic input, or are you taking the entire regexp as input? Etc. One idea is you find the group names in the regexp. If you are building the regexp yourself, it may be easier to take the group names from whatever building blocks you’re using than from the final regexp string, I cannot tell.